# How to pass GUID for wix patch?

Tags: wix, msp

I am using PatchCreation properties for creating wix based patch.

```
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">

  <!-- Creating patch from latest and old msi -->
  <!-- PatchCreation id need to be changed for every new patch release -->
  <PatchCreation
        Id="8EF65292-867D-4C59-8E1B-25B014D79883"
        CleanWorkingFolder="yes"
        OutputPath="patch.pcp"
        WholeFilesOnly="yes" 
        >

    <PatchInformation
        Description="TimeConversion Small Update Patch"
        Comments="TimeConversion Small Update Patch"
        Manufacturer="MyOrganization"
    />

    <PatchMetadata
        AllowRemoval="yes"
        Description="TimeConversion Small Update Patch"
        ManufacturerName="MyOrganization"
        TargetProductName="TimeConversionPatch"
        MoreInfoURL="http://www.MyOrganization.com/"
        Classification="Update"
        DisplayName="TimeConversion Patch" 
        MinorUpdateTargetRTM="1"/>

    <!-- Uncompressed msi should be used to create patch-->
    <Family DiskId="5000"
        MediaSrcProp="Sample"
        Name="Sample"
        SequenceStart="5000">
      <UpgradeImage SourceFile="$(var.RootFolder)\TimeConversion\Impl\Patch\Latest_Uncompressed_MSI\TimeConversionService.msi" Id="Latest">
        <TargetImage SourceFile="$(var.RootFolder)\TimeConversion\Impl\Patch\Prev_Uncompressed_MSI\TimeConversionService.msi" Order="2" Id="Previous" IgnoreMissingFiles="no"/>
      </UpgradeImage>
    </Family>

    <PatchSequence 
            PatchFamily="SamplePatchFamily"
            Supersede="yes" 
    />

  </PatchCreation>
```

How to pass new guid to PatchCreation id value via candle.exe parameter?

Comment: Have you explored using Wix Pre-Processor variables? http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/overview/preprocessor.html   Instead of the guid, you could use a pre-processor variable such as $(var.PatchGuid) and pass the value of  PatchGuid on the command line using candle.exe. This should work unless you have already tried this.

Comment: @KiranHegde It worked . thanks